# Post injections into Site Origins Page builder

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, categories

I am using this code below to insert into every single post. I'm using a plugin called Head, Footer and Post Injections to insert that code.

However, I am currently redoing every post with Site Origin Page Builder, and that code no longer works.

Is there a way to alter this code to work with page builder?

```
<H3>Genres</H3>
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';

// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids,
        'child_of' => 2
    ) );

    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // Display post categories.
    echo  $terms;
} ?></BR>
<H3>Availabilities</H3>
<?php
$taxonomy = 'category';

// Get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Separator between links.
$separator = ', ';

if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );

    $terms = wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'style'    => 'none',
        'echo'     => false,
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'include'  => $term_ids,
        'child_of' => 42,
        'depth'    => 3,
    ) );

    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // Display post categories.
    echo  $terms;


} ?>
```